# Order the lines of the array in ascending order of the number of equal elements in each line

Tags: c

The number of lines, colums and elements are intoduces by the user.

In C

For example, I have the array:

```
1 1 0 3
2 0 0 0
2 3 4 5
3 3 3 3
```

it should show up as this:

```
2 3 4 5
1 1 0 3
2 0 0 0
3 3 3 3
```

Right now I'm stuck. I've tried to give for every row a "1" if there are any equal elemnts, then I wanted to sum up these numbers, a based on that to order the lines. I thinked about turning every line into an array , compare the equal elements , and then rearrange them, but I don't know how to to this.

The part of the code that I have at the moment:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < m; k++) {
            if (tab[i][j] == tab[i][k]) {
                k1++;
                if (k1 > 1) {
                    k1--;
                }
                printf("a[%d]%d\n", i, k1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some kind of data structure to store the repeated number you find in each row, so that you can consult it after looping through the entire input matrix.

A solution could consist in creating a `R x 10` matrix, where `R` is the number of rows in the input matrix. In each column you store how many repetitions there are for the number at that index in the given row.

For your input, you should end up with something like this:

```
1 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

At this point, you can order the rows based on which row contains the greatest number.

Obviously there may be other solution, but I think this one is conceptually simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is a demonstration. Modify the size of the array and select the appropriate data type according to your actual situation
**First enter the number of rows and columns of the matrix. Then comes the matrix data.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
int m,n;
typedef struct Node{
int data[100];
int repTime;
}Node;


int cmp(const void* a,const void* b){
 return ((Node*)a)->repTime >((Node*)b)->repTime;
}
int main(){
        Node num[1000];
        int time[1000];
        memset(num,0,sizeof(num));
        scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                  int k;
                  scanf("%d",&k);
                  num[i].data[j]=k;
                  time[k]++;
                  if(time[k]>num[i].repTime){
                        num[i].repTime = num[i].data[k];
                  }
                }
        }
    qsort(num,m,sizeof(struct Node),cmp);
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                  printf("%d ",num[i].data[j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```